# Obtain coefficients of a line from 2 points

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I wish to use two points say $(x_1$,$y_1)$ and $(x_2$,$y_2)$ and obtain the coefficients of the line in the  following form: $$ Ax + By + C = 0$$

Is there any direct formula to compute.

Comment: Is it possible to restate $y=mx+b$ in the form of "Ax+By+C=0"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\text{slope} = m = \dfrac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1} \Rightarrow y - y_1 = m(x-x_1) = \dfrac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}\left(x-x_1\right) \Rightarrow (x_2-x_1)y - y_1(x_2-x_1) = (y_2-y_1)x - x_1(y_2-y_1) \Rightarrow -(y_2-y_1)x + (x_2-x_1)y -y_1(x_2-x_1) +x_1(y_2-y_1)=0$. This gives the formula:

$A = y_1-y_2$

$B = x_2-x_1$

$C = x_1y_2-x_2y_1$

Comment: It is recommended that when the OP shows no effort at the problem, you should not give away the answer. See my answer as an example.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Set the values of $x,y$ to form two linear simultaneous equation for the unknowns $A,B$

Solve for $A,B$ in terms of $C, x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2$

Answer (score 0):

This is called solving simultaneous equations and is a matter of algebra. There are two ways to go about this but they are almost the same and have the same spirit.

The first way to do it is to solve directly for $A,B,C$ by substituting the points into $Ax+By+C=0$ to get $$ \begin {eqnarray*} Ax_1 + By_1 &=& -C, \\ Ax_2 + By_2 &=& -C. \end {eqnarray*} $$Do you know how to [solve such a system](http://www.webmath.com/solver2.html)?

The second method involves finding the slope of the line, $ m = \frac {y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1} $, and then substitute one of the points into the [slope-intercept form](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/strtlneq.htm) of the line. For example, $$ y_2 = mx_2 + b, $$ and solve for $b$: $$ b = y_2 - mx_2 = y_1 - mx_1. $$Then, you have the equation in the form $ y = mx + b $. Now, you can rearrange terms to get it in the form $ Ax + By + C = 0 $.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ways of finding values of $A$, $B$, and $C$.

**Method 1:**  A line is the set of points $\vec{x}$ such that
$$\vec{a}\cdot \vec{x_0} = \vec{a} \cdot \vec{x}$$
where $x_0$ is an arbitrary point on the line and $\vec{a}$ is a nonzero vector perpendicular to the line.  We know that the line will be parallel to the vector
$$\vec{d} = \langle x_2-x_1, y_2-y_1\rangle,$$
so $\vec{a}$ will be a vector perpendicular to $\vec{d}$.  One such vector is 
$$\vec{a} = \langle y_1-y_2, x_2 - x_1\rangle$$
Let's suppose that $\vec{x} = \langle x, y\rangle$ is a point on the line.  Then, $\vec{x}$ satisfies
$$\vec{a} \cdot \vec{x_0} = \vec{a} \cdot \vec{x}$$
$$\langle y_1-y_2, x_2 - x_1\rangle \cdot \langle x_1, y_1\rangle = \langle y_1-y_2, x_2 - x_1\rangle \cdot \langle x, y \rangle$$
$$y_2x_1 - x_2 y_1 = (y_1 - y_2)x + (x_2 - x_1)y$$
$$(y_1 - y_2)x + (x_2 - x_1) y + x_2y_1 - y_2x_1 = 0$$
So
$$A = y_1 - y_2$$
$$B = x_2 - x_1$$
$$C = x_2y_1 - y_2x_1$$

**Method 2:** Just plug your two points into the equation $Ax + By + C = 0$:
$$Ax_1 + By_1 + C = 0 \tag{1}$$
$$Ax_2 + By_2 + C = 0 \tag{2}$$
Subtracting (1) from (2) gives us
$$A(x_2 - x_1) + B(y_2 - y_1) = 0$$
Of course, $A = B = 0$ is a solution, but it will not give us a line.  Another solution is $B = (x_2 - x_1)$, $A = (y_1 - y_2)$.  Since $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ were distinct points, $A$ and $B$ are not both zero.  Now let us solve for $C$ using (1):
$$(y_1-y_2)x_1+(x_2-x_1)y_1 + C = 0$$
$$y_1x_1 - y_2x_1 + x_2y_1 - x_1y_1 + C = 0$$
$$C = y_2x_1 - x_2y_1$$

---

It's worth pointing out that there is no *unique* solution to your problem.  If $$Ax + By + C = 0$$
is one solution, then
$$\lambda Ax + \lambda By + \lambda C = 0 \qquad \lambda \not= 0$$
is another way of expressing the same line.

Answer (score 0):

You can also remark that $$Ax + By + C = 0=\alpha x+ y + \gamma$$ (with $\alpha=\frac AB$,$\gamma=\frac CB$) and then, applying the conditions, $$\alpha x_1+ y_1 + \gamma=0$$ $$\alpha x_2+ y_2 + \gamma=0$$ and you have to solve for $\alpha $ and $\gamma$ two linear equations. Using the classical methods, you get $$\alpha=-\frac{{y_1}-{y_2}}{{x_1}-{x_2}}$$ $$\gamma=\frac{{x_2} {y_1}-{x_1} {y_2}}{{x_1}-{x_2}}$$ So, now, to make the expression nicer, set $B=(x_1-x_2)$ and $A=\alpha B=(y_2-y_1)$ and $C=\gamma B=({x_2} {y_1}-{x_1} {y_2})$